How to Remove EXIF Metadata from Images in Laravel While Preserving Quality and Size?
I'm working on a Laravel project where users can upload profile images. One of my requirements is to strip EXIF metadata (including sensitive details like location) from these images before storing them. I want to ensure that the images maintain their original size and quality after removing the metadata.
Currently, I am using the Intervention\Image package, and my existing code looks like this:
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
$image = Image::make($request->file('image'));

How can I effectively remove EXIF metadata from images while preserving their quality and dimensions in Laravel?
